# Access http post data in Handler

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Would like to access this site and receive JSON result in my lamda handler. Here is the code I have. Is there a working example of making a http call in node.js I can model?

```
const TornadaWarningIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'TornadoWarningIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        var speakOutput = 'The Tornado is located at 123 Main St, Oregon Wisconsin. The storm is 13 miles to your southwest moving northeast at 45 miles per hour. Say repeat or Continue..';
        const request = require('request');
        request.post('https://api.weather.gov/points/38.8894,-77.0352', { json: { key: 'value' } }, (error, res, body) => {
        if (error) {
           speakOutput = "there was error in API call"
            .speak(speakOutput)
            return;
         }
            
         });
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt('Say continue for details...')
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

This code just drops through to generic handler that says it having trouble doing what I asked.
This seems to be a standard activity that I am not finding any boiler plate code to achieve. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean just make the request and access to the response I do recommend to you using 'axios' instead of 'request'. e.g:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

or using async/await:

```
async function getUser() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Taken from axios documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Don't really want to use additional source if I don't have to. Can't this be easily done in node.js ? Seems like a very common use case.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors I can spot in your code:

1. The

   `return handlerInput.responseBuilder`
   `.speak(speakOutput)`
   `.reprompt('Say continue for details...')`
   `.getResponse();`.

code block was outside of the callback function from the request.post().

2. Your error handler code doesn't make sense:

`if (error) {`
 `speakOutput = "there was error in API call"`
 `.speak(speakOutput)`
 `return;`
`}`

You need to return  handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(speakOutput).getResponse();

I suspect the code was hitting the error condition and then not returning a coherent response.  Your error handler should log the error object to see what the underlying error is.